# How to execute a update query in spark sql temp tables

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying the below code but it is throwing some random error that I am unable to understand:

```py
df.registerTempTable("Temp_table")

spark.sql("Update Temp_table set column_a='1'")
```

Comment: please share the error traceback as text.

Comment: This is the main error i am getting now '"message": "An error occurred while calling o69.sql.\n: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: UPDATE TABLE is not supported temporarily.'; any workaround please?

Comment: use df api (`.withColumn()`), to overwrite the column

Comment: Can you please share me an example? If possible with multiple joins. I could not find a better example for this

Comment: then your stated question is different from your problem at hand. maybe ask a new question with your problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

Currently spark sql does not support UPDATE statments. The workaround is to use create a delta lake / iceberg table using your spark dataframe and execute you sql query directly on this table.

For iceberg implementation refer to :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format-iceberg.html